# Correct way of using "Buy-stop-limit" to purchase stocks when price goes below a value

Tags: stock-markets, stock-exchanges

I see everywhere explanations of "sell-stop-limit" (to sell your stocks) and I found an explanation of "buy-stop-limit" for when you want to buy stocks once the value starts rising. However I don't understand how to use it when I'm looking to buy after the price went down.

For example, let's say a stock valued at 102$ on the market that I want to buy when it reaches 100$. My bank requires both "stop" AND "limit" values when I use the buy-stop function. So I suppose I should set stop=98$ but I don't know what impact will the limit value have.

- With stop=100$ and limit=101$

  Will it trigger once it goes below 100$ but not buy if it goes back up above 101$ when order passes ?
- With stop=100$ and limit=98$

  Will it trigger once it goes below 100$ but not buy if it reached less than 98$ when order passes ?
- Or am I completely wrong and a buy-stop value only trigger on the way up (from 99.99$ to 100$, but not from 100.01$ to 100$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A buy stop order is an order where you buy if price moves above the current price.   Here's [an example](http://www.solerinvestments.com/Online-Trading/Buy-Stop-Limit-Order.htm).

If XYZ is $102 and you want to buy it at $100 then just place a limit order.

Conditional orders can be used for more complex orders, if your broker offers them.

Comment: Thanks for that! I thought only buy-stop orders were "triggered". Didn't know that limit-orders were also triggered once the price went down, thought it was just a failsafe and the order was canceled if the price was higher than when the order was requested!

Answer (score 1):

A limit defines the most you want to pay for the stock. If there is a stock that's at $102 and you are willing to buy it for $100 or less, then a plain limit order will do that.

But is sounds like you want to buy at $100 only if it goes below $100 and comes back *up* which is not common.

For a buy, a "stop" defines a trigger price that the stock must go *above* to execute. They're traditionally called "stop-loss" orders, and more commonly used to sell meaning you want to "stop the bleeding" and sell when the price hits a price reflecting the most you want to lose.  For a buy it would be used to stop losses on a *short* position, meaning you want to sell if the price goes above a certain amount (stopping your losses on a short).

There's not (to my knowledge) a common order type to trigger a buy if a stock *rises*. Why would you want to but it at a *higher* price that you can now?

You may need to see if your broker supports custom conditional orders to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, very useful answer and it's solid clear knowledge that "limit" is always the most I want to pay for, whether it's a limit-order or a buy-stop-limit order. I accepted the other answer as it was posted first but both your answers are exactly what I needed.

Comment: Actually mine was posted first :) but that's ok - I'm not concerned about rep at this point. Glad it helped.